# php MySQL - mixed up output

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am programming my first page with php und mysql. Now I encountered an error I can't solve by myself. If look at the picture, the first three columns are case1 the next is case2 and the last is case3.
Now my problem is, that only the first and last table were displayed correct. The second and third table are missing the "Distanz" column. The fourth table is completely mixed up.

Hopefully you could point out my error. Thanks in advance.

[image: The output of given code]

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
$statement_anzeigeart = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM sportart WHERE infoart_id = :infoart_id");
$statement_infoart_1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, datum, dauer, distanz, hr, belast_koerp, belast_ment, gewicht FROM daten WHERE user_id = :user_id AND sportart = :sportart AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY datum LIMIT :limit");
$statement_infoart_2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, datum, dauer, hr, saetze, wdhl, belast_koerp, belast_ment, gewicht FROM daten WHERE user_id = :user_id AND sportart = :sportart AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY datum LIMIT :limit");
$statement_infoart_3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, datum, dauer, uebungen, hr, belast_koerp, belast_ment, gewicht FROM daten WHERE user_id = :user_id AND sportart = :sportart AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY datum LIMIT :limit");

include 'edit.inc.php';
include 'delete.inc.php';
?>

<?php
if(!isset($_GET['sportart'])){
    for($infoart_id=1;$infoart_id<=3;$infoart_id++){
        $statement_anzeigeart->execute(array($infoart_id));
        while($sportart_sql = $statement_anzeigeart->fetch()){
            $sportart = $sportart_sql['id'];
            $limit = "3";

                                            $statement_infoart_3->execute(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'sportart' => $sportart, 'limit' => $limit));


            switch($infoart_id){
                case 1: 
                    $statement_infoart_1->execute(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'sportart' => $sportart, 'limit' => $limit));

                    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>
                            <h2 class='sub-header'><a href='?seite=report&sportart=".$sportart_sql['id']."'>".$sportart_sql['name']."</a> </h2>
                                <table class='table table-striped table-condensed'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Datum</th>                
                                            <th>Dauer</th>
                                            <th>Distanz</th>
                                            <th>HR</th>
                                            <th>Belastung (physisch)</th>
                                            <th>Belastung (mental)</th>                
                                            <th>Gewicht</th>
                                            <th>Aktionen</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>";

                    while($activity1 = $statement_infoart_1->fetch()){
                        echo "          <tr>
                                            <td>".$activity1['datum']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity1['dauer']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity1['distanz']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity1['hr']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity1['belast_koerp']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity1['belast_ment']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity1['gewicht']."</td>
                                            <td><a href='?seite=report&edit=".$activity1['id']."' class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a> <a href='?seite=report&delete=".$activity1['id']."' class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></td>  
                                        </tr>";
                    } //endwhile
                    echo            "</tbody>
                                </table>    
                        </div>";                
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $statement_infoart_2->execute(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'sportart' => $sportart, 'limit' => $limit));

                    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>
                            <h2 class='sub-header'><a href='?seite=report&sportart=".$sportart_sql['id']."'>".$sportart_sql['name']."</a> </h2>
                                <table class='table table-striped table-condensed'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Datum</th>                
                                            <th>Dauer</th>
                                            <th>Sätze</th>
                                            <th>Wdhl</th>
                                            <th>HR</th>
                                            <th>Belastung (physisch)</th>
                                            <th>Belastung (mental)</th>                
                                            <th>Gewicht</th>
                                            <th>Aktionen</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>";
                    while($activity2 = $statement_infoart_2->fetch()){
                        echo "          <tr>
                                            <td>".$activity2['datum']." 1</td>
                                            <td>".$activity2['dauer']." 2</td>
                                            <td>".$activity2['saetze']." 3</td>
                                            <td>".$activity2['wdhl']." 4</td>
                                            <td>".$activity2['hr']." 5</td>
                                            <td>".$activity2['belast_koerp']." 6</td>
                                            <td>".$activity2['belast_ment']." 7</td>
                                            <td>".$activity2['gewicht']." 8</td>
                                            <td><a href='?seite=report&bearbeiten=".$activity2['id']."' class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a> <a href='?seite=report&delete=".$activity2['id']."' class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></td>  
                                        </tr>" ;
                    }   //endwhile  
                    echo            "</tbody>
                                </table>    
                        </div>";                        
                    break;
                case 3:
                $statement_infoart_3->execute(array('user_id' => $user_id, 'sportart' => $sportart, 'limit' => $limit));
                    echo "<div class='table-responsive'>
                            <h2 class='sub-header'><a href='?seite=report&sportart=".$sportart_sql['id']."'>".$sportart_sql['name']."</a> </h2>
                                <table class='table table-striped table-condensed'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Datum</th>                
                                            <th>Dauer</th>  
                                            <th>Übungen</th>
                                            <th>HR</th>
                                            <th>Belastung (physisch)</th>
                                            <th>Belastung (mental)</th>                
                                            <th>Gewicht</th>
                                            <th>Aktionen</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>";
                    while($activity3 = $statement_infoart_3->fetch()){
                        echo "          <tr>
                                            <td>".$activity3['datum']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity3['dauer']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity3['uebungen']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity3['hr']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity3['belast_koerp']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity3['belast_ment']."</td>
                                            <td>".$activity3['gewicht']."</td>
                                            <td><a href='?seite=report&bearbeiten=".$activity3['id']."' class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a> <a href='?seite=report&delete=".$activity3['id']."' class='btn btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></td>  
                                        </tr>" ;
                    }   //endwhile
                    echo            "</tbody>
                                </table>    
                        </div>";
                    break;
            }
        } // endwhile
    } //endfor
} //endif   
?>
```

Comment: No way I'm combing through this much code...can you narrow it down? Have you checked your error log?

Comment: Your best hope of debugging this is to try to create a really small example. For example what happens if you completely remove all but the second table, and all but the distanz column in that table.

Comment: There's no `distanz` in `$statement_infoart_2` or `$statement_infoart_3`. Why should that be in those cases?

Comment: Check 5,6 line :you have not define distanz

Comment: The `Distanz` column isn't missing. There's nothing in `case 2` or `case 3` that says to print a column with that name.

Comment: @NareshTeli yeah I know that and that is correct. The first three tables are case1. So there is only missing the value for the "Distanz" column.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob After I moved the statement execution into the cases the first case works correct. but the other cases only displays the table head and wont fetch any data from the database.

No errors in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly why, but after I switched emulated prepares back on and changed the prepare, so that it won't use :limit, everything works fine.